# Rxjs combineAll with double map wrap

Tags: rxjs, observable, angularfire2

I am using AngularFire2. I want to retrieve the list of the user's chats and for each chat determine if the last message if has been emitted after the user has left the chat.

To do so I retrieve the chat list through the function getUserChatList() that returns a FirebaseListObservable.

It looks like we cannot use the map operator directly on the list, we need to double map it.

Once done I retrieve the last message of each chat and if I determine that one message is unread I set the anyUnread variable to true.

I must wait that every chat has been processed so I use the combineAll().

It looks like my code never goes to the last map (the return statement). Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

```
watchUnreadMessages() {
    // Retrieve all chats
    this.subscription =
    this.msgService.getUserChatList()
    .map( chats => {
      chats.map( chat => {
        console.log('chat ', chat)
        let lastPresence = chat.lastPresence;
        return this.msgService.getLastMessage(chat.$key)
        .map( lastMess => {
          console.log('lastMess ', lastMess)
          if (lastMess[0].timestamp >= lastPresence)
          this.anyUnread = true;
        });
      })
    })
    .combineAll( () => {
      let unread = this.anyUnread;
      return unread
    }).subscribe( (unread) => console.log('unread: ', unread) );


  }
```

*** EDIT ***
Tried to use mergMap as @kit suggested which works with simple example but in my case still have some blocking errors

Tried simple first:

```
this.msgService.getUserChatList().flatMap( chats =>
      Observable.from(chats).flatMap( (chat, i) => {
            console.log ('chat, ', chat);
            return Observable.of(chat);
      })
      .last()
    )
    .subscribe( () => console.log('Finished') )
```

It display chat1, chat2 and finished (the order is perfect). Note that the chats contains properties such as $key and lastPresence.

Now I wanted to add complexity:

```
this.msgService.getUserChatList()
      .flatMap( chat => {
        return this.msgService.getLastMessage(chat.$key).map( lastMess => {
          return this.containsUnreadMessages(lastMess, chat.lastPresence);
        })
      } )
      .last()
    )
    .subscribe( () => console.log('Finished') )
```

The code can't even be compiled as the debugger tells me that properties $key and lastPresence doesn't exist in type {}... it's driving me crazy!

Comment: for sure you have to add return "return chats.map( chat => {" in 6th line

Comment: Yes you're right. I added a return statement (or just removed the {}) but still note displaying 'lastMess'... :s

Answer (score 0):

ok, sot this could be done better but maybe you will take some inspiration from it:

```
const arr = [
    [{timestamp: 1}],
    [{timestamp: 1}],
    [{timestamp: 3}],
];

Rx.Observable.from([
    {lastPresence: 1},
    {lastPresence: 2},
    {lastPresence: 3},
])
.flatMap((chat, i) => {
    return Rx.Observable.of(arr[i]).map((lastMess) => lastMess[0].timestamp >= chat.lastPresence ? 1:0);
})
.scan((counter, one) => counter + one, 0)
.last()
.subscribe((unread) => console.log('unread: ', unread));
```

Comment: that's indeed a good start. I tried to adapt your example but in my case I cannot call any property of the chat object... debugger tells me that property doesn't exist in type {}. But am sure this property exists because if I simply log the object to the console, I can see it... any idea?

Comment: you have to paste code, my example was just a suggestion.